# If-statement: list of values

Tags: c++, if-statement

I have a use-case where I want to run code, but only when one of my variables has a valid value (the value comes from a sensor). To be valid, it needs to be greater than -1500, smaller than +1500, and not have a value of -1, 0 or +1. Right now what I do is:

```
if ((a > -1500 && a < -1) || (a > 1 && a < 1500) {
```

However, this criteria is being repeated A LOT throughout my code, and it would be so much easier if I could define somewhere in my code what this range of valid values are, so I could simply do:

```
if (valid) {
```

What is the best approach for this?

To clarify: I do not know how to tell the system what values are valid

Comment: `if (valid(a))`?

Comment: When `a` is modified, add something like `valid = (a > -1500 && a < -1) || (a > 1 && a < 1500)`.   Then test `if (valid)` ...   To prevent such code being duplicated, put the logic in a function.     Alternatively, put your checking code into a separate function, and test `if (IsValid(a))`.

Answer (score 4):

> What is the best approach for this?

Add a function.

```
bool isInputValid(int a)
{
    return (a > -1500 && a < -1) || (a > 1 && a < 1500);
}
```

and then use

```
if ( isInputValid(a) ) {  ... }
```

where ever you need to run that check.

Further refinement:

```
bool isInRange(int a, int low, int high)
{
    return (a > low && a < high);
}

bool isInputValid(int a)
{
    return (isInRange(a, -1500, -1) || isInRange(a, 1, 1500));
}
```

Comment: What? A function? Luxury. We used to do this with a macro. And sometimes we didn't even have a macro, only a shoe box. /s

Comment: @wally, macros in C++? No way if a function will do the job.

Comment: Added /s to be clear. I abhor macros. But it is nice that the question has both answers.

Comment: @wally everybody has their believes, R Sahu comes from C++ where there are some commodities that are not available in C

Comment: @wally, Is that, /s, some sort of code word? I am certainly not aware of it if that's the case.

Comment: @RSahu "/s" -- sarcasm

Comment: something like a sarcasm tag closure.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie and wally, thanks for the clarification and contributing to my LOTD :)

Comment: It's not even sarcasm, it's a pop culture reference. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four_Yorkshiremen_sketch